# How to convert MYSQL to PL/SQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql

This is my MYSQL code. Here I want to convert This to PL/SQL

```
Select 
products.productID,
products.productName,
orderDetails.quantity,
orderDetails.unitPrice,
orderDetails.unitPrice*orderDetails.quantity as sub_total,
orderDetails.discount as taxes 
from products 
inner join Orderdetails on products.productID=orderDetails.productID
```

How can I Convert this to PL/SQL?

Comment: What is the syntax error (if any) reporting in PL/SQL?

Comment: Seems you need to use that SQL Select statement within Oracle DB. It will work for Oracle provided that those tables with those columns are created within the Oracle DB also. Since, there's nothing unrelated to standard SQL syntax within this query. On the other hand, PL/SQL, which stands for representing a programming language containing some code blocks within Oracle DB, is a differenent concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PL/SQL means "Oracle", as it is its procedural extension to SQL. In other words, we write "queries" in SQL, and we write procedures, functions, packages, triggers and stuff in PL/SQL.

If you're just confused and - actually - want to run that query in Oracle's SQL, you don't have to do anything as it would work just fine (presuming tables with those columns exist in a schema you're connected to). Though, I'd suggest you to use table aliases as they make code easier to read, e.g.

```
select 
  p.productid,
  p.productname,
  o.quantity,
  o.unitprice,
  o.unitprice * o.quantity as sub_total,
  o.discount as taxes 
from products p inner join orderdetails o on p.productid = o.productid;
```

---

If you really wanted to switch to PL/SQL, then an anonymous PL/SQL block would do (i.e. you don't need a procedure or a function; what you *really* need depends on what you want to do next). In PL/SQL, you have to select `INTO` something; for example, into locally declared variables. However, as your query doesn't contain `where` clause, it would return all rows whose `productid` values match in both tables, and that can be no rows, one row or many rows. For no rows, you'd have to handle `no_data_found` exception. For one row, it would work. For many rows, you'd have to handle `too_many_rows` exception. Therefore, it might be a good idea to use a cursor `FOR` loop - that's what I'll demonstrate - and simply display what's being found to the screen (I'll display only two values, though):

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  for cur_r in (select 
                  p.productid,
                  p.productname,
                  o.quantity,
                  o.unitprice,
                  o.unitprice * o.quantity as sub_total,
                  o.discount as taxes 
                from products p inner join orderdetails o on p.productid = o.productid
               )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.productname ||', '|| cur_r.sub_total);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

---

As I said: how that code would really look like depends on what you want to do with it.